# Issue with dell omsa packages on Centos 7

Tags: centos, centos7, dell, dell-poweredge, dell-openmanage

I have a Dell 2950 with Centos 7 and Dell OMSA packages installed. When I try to update the server with "yum update" I have the following dependences issue:

```
Error: Package: dell_ie_rac_5-8.1.0-4.1.128.el7.x86_64 (@dell-omsa-indep)
       Requires: srvadmin-racadm5 = 8.1.0
       Removing: srvadmin-racadm5-8.1.0-4.1.128.el7.x86_64 (@dell-omsa-indep                                                                             )
           srvadmin-racadm5 = 8.1.0-4.1.128.el7
       Updated By: srvadmin-racadm5-8.3.0-1908.9058.el7.x86_64 (dell-omsa-in                                                                             dep)
           srvadmin-racadm5 = 8.3.0-1908.9058.el7
Error: Package: python-smbios-2.2.27-4.4.1.el7.x86_64 (@dell-omsa-indep)
           Requires: libsmbios = 2.2.27-4.4.1.el7
           Removing: libsmbios-2.2.27-4.4.1.el7.x86_64 (@dell-omsa-indep)
               libsmbios = 2.2.27-4.4.1.el7
           Updated By: libsmbios-2.2.27-1908.9058.el7.x86_64 (dell-omsa-indep)
               libsmbios = 2.2.27-1908.9058.el7
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

What is the safer solution in this case? Ignore/Skip the dependences is not an option for me

Comment: Contact the repository maintainer. They appear to have broken something.

Comment: I'll try to write to the Dell support since the repository is maintained by them but I'm pretty sure that they will reply that everything is ok

Comment: Ha. This would not be the first time they'd broken their repo.

Comment: Nice to hear :D I wrote to them. I hope they will be fix quickly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Dell doesn't want to fix their repo issue so the only solution that I have found is that post (http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/servers/f/177/t/19952237)

```
yum remove dell_ie_rac python-smbios
yum update
```